# ApplePay - Decrypting token using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a Vue app that uses ApplePay but I'm stuck on decrypting the token. I'm using this package but the error I'm getting is a little strange and I don't understand it.

All I'm doing is running this to make sure the package is installed:

```
mounted() {
    const PaymentToken = require('apple-pay-decrypt');
    console.log(PaymentToken);
},
```

And this is the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/x509'
at webpackMissingModule (index.js?b266:1)
at eval (index.js?b266:1)
at Object../node_modules/x509/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:13419)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:785)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.eval (index.js?da5a:1)
at eval (index.js:110)
at Object../node_modules/apple-pay-decrypt/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:274)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:785)
at fn (app.js:151)
```

x509 does exist in node_modules and .build/Realse/x509 also exists but it contains a file called x509.node as opposed to a .js file.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to make this work?

Comment: Do you trie to use that module in the browser?

Comment: Yes, and that's the output I get in the console when using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully read the description of the modules you are using:

[Apple Pay Decrypt](https://github.com/samcorcos/apple-pay-decrypt#readme):

> […]This works in node and not on a browser, as it requires the built-in crypto package and secret keys (.pem files), which should never exist on the client anyway.[…]

So, on the one hand, it won't run in the browser due to the dependencies to `crypt` (and `x509`) and even if it would, then you shouldn't do that due to the information you would expose.

Comment: Damn, a complete oversight on my behalf. Thank you for that. Looks like it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Dally whenever you work with critical things like payments you need to be extremely careful about which information can, and which must not exists on the client-side. Otherwise, someone else can use this information to do payments in your name, making you lose money or getting legal problems.